# well ordering principle and ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, ordered-fields, well-orders

I am trying to prove that there is no integer between $0$ and $1$. The standard proof uses well ordering principle. But if one takes integers as subset of rationals and rational numbers as an ordered field, by contradiction if there exists any integer $N$ (which is repeated addition of multiplicative identity $N$ times) between $0$ and $1$, then ordered field is failed.

Now the question is, does this mean that well ordering principle is someway followed when one defines an order on the field satisfying field structure? So a total order on a field satisfying field structure contains well ordering theorem? I am not bothered about real numbers as I am not using any completeness property

Comment: part of exercise. and how well i really know something?

Comment: "So a total order on a field satisfying field structure contains well ordering theorem" What does that mean? How can a *structure* contain a *theorem*?

Comment: I meant implies instead of contains.

Comment: I still don't understand what that means ...

Comment: The standard proof uses well ordering of integers and if I consider rationals as ordered field, then I can prove the same problem( no integer between 0 and 1) by contradiction. Now this must mean that "well ordering of naturals", is somehow implied by ordered field of rationals, since two different concepts inpedendently prove samething, then they must be equivalent somehow. I just don't see how.